# Do I have to help my enemy change his flat tire?

Tags: vehicles-transportation, mishpatim

We learn in Parshat Mishpatim ([Shemot 23:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0223.htm#5)):

> If thou see the ass of him that hateth thee lying under its burden, thou shalt forbear to pass by him; thou shalt surely release it with him.

My question is whether the obligation to help an enemy with his burden is specifically because of the animal, or if this generalizes to similar situations.  If my enemy has driven his car into a ditch, or is on the side of the road with a flat tire, must I stop and help him under this commandment, or does this only apply to an animal and not a vehicle because of *tz'aar ba'alei chayim*, not causing unnecessary harm or distress to animals?

Rashi here talks a lot about when one is obligated to help unload, and a note in Rashi led me to Bava Metzia 32 where there is discussion about unloading versus loading (and about "*with* him").  The g'mara there mentions both financial loss and suffering of the animal but these seem to be kind of tangential to its main discussion.  (But I have not learned this g'mara before and might be missing something.)  Plus, the g'mara probably doesn't have the final word on the matter.

While pre-modern rabbinic writings won't address flat tires, there might be discussions of broken wagon wheels or axles.

Comment: Note the same obligation applies to helping a friend. Enemy means even your enemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rambam ends his Laws of the Murderer and Preservation of Life actually saying it's not about the donkey -- it's about this guy might get stuck on the road at night and it would be dangerous for him. As someone being stuck on the highway could also be in danger, I would think it's very much within the spirit of the law:

> ואף על פי שעדיין לא עשה תשובה--אם מצאו נבהל במשאו--מצוה לפרוק ולטעון עימו, ולא יניחנו נוטה למות:  שמא ישתהה בשביל ממונו, ויבוא לידי סכנה; והתורה הקפידה על נפשות ישראל, בין רשעים בין צדיקים, מאחר שהם נלווים אל ה' ומאמינים בעיקר הדת, שנאמר "אמור אליהם חי אני נאום ה' אלוהים, אם אחפוץ במות הרשע, כי אם בשוב רשע מדרכו, וחיה"
>
> Even if this [enemy] has not yet repented -- if you see him obsessed with his luggage, it is a mitzvah to unload and reload it with him, **not to leave him there on the path towards death: as he may stay behind because of his property, and he could come to a dangerous situation.**

Rambam is saying the guy could safely walk away, but won't do so because he cares too much about this merchandise of his. The argument would be even stronger if someone is stranded on the highway when they can't even safely walk away.